# Youtube API v3 - Can I get 50M quota per user if using Access Token(Oauth2)?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Can I get 50M quota per user if using Access Token(Oauth2) with Youtube Api v3?
Or will it be bound to my Project ApiKey, and therefore I will only get a quota of total 50,000,000 for my application ?

thx! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quota usage for the YouTube API is project based not user account based.

So if I authenticate your application / project and make 10,000,000 requests, then you authenticate application and make 40,000,000 you will have blown the quota out.

There is one quota that is user based `Per-user limit   3,000 requests/second/user` but this can be gotten around by sending a random `quotaUser` with all of your request. This tells the API that each request comes from a different user, but I didn't tell you about this.